# docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint funny_golick

Tags: sql-server, docker

I am trying to run a docker to run Microsoft SQL Server 2019 in my ubuntu 20.04 OS.
For that reason I write my terminal:

```
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server
```

then I write

```
sudo docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=Zima1000' -p 1433:1433 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```

then it send this messege

```
7faf65528d4d0fe12567afb6b0b39a07cd060c3974a0b77ac6c0e66f19c23e57
```

docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint funny_golick (8946bfd95b1e65fb700ffa4fe457d3de30c8d11a9c8a8f286ebebc70af096d19): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:1433: bind: address already in use.

plese help how I can fix it.

Comment: From your error message, it indicates port 1433 is already in use on either the docker VM or possibly directly on your laptop. You can either stop whatever is running on that port, or change the port used in your Docker, command.

Comment: And sometimes restarting the docker or restarting the computer also resolves

Answer (score 1):

The error says that port 1433 is already in use. You should change to use a different port.